# WPF DataGrid Validation Bug?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, gridview

This may be intended functionality, but it sure seems like a bug to me.

I'm using the out-of-the-box WPF DataGrid, bound to an ObservableCollection and *attempting* to use some validation rules in order to provide nice user feedback. Needless to say there are more issues than I can count, but I'll stick with the immediate.

Here is a summary of the problem:

1. Bind `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection<T>`
2. Populate the collection
3. Edit an item in the grid in a way which will cause a validation error
4. Programatically remove that item from the `ObservableCollection<T>`

When these steps are performed, the GridView properly recognizes that the item has been removed from the collection, and removes the row from the grid. However, **the Grid is now stuck in an invalid state and no further actions can be performed through the UI on the Grid!**

Again, this seems quite like a major bug to me as being able to programmatically remove items from a collection is kind of a big deal.

Has anybody run into this? Any suggestions for how to get around it?

It is worth noting that I have created a separate solution just to isolate this problem, but to answers some questions you might have:

*Does your object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?* **YES**

*Is this a custom collection?* **No plain old `ObservableCollection<T>`**

*How are you removing items from your collection?*

```
//Find any newly added item and remove it  
var someObject = SomeObjects
             .Where(obj => obj.SomeProperty == SomeValue)
             .First();

SomeObjects.Remove(someObject );
```

*How are you binding your validation rule?*

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeProperty">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="SomeProperty">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <val:RequiredValidator ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" 
                     ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

*What does your validation rule look like?*

```
public class RequiredValidator : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as String))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required!");

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in when and where *exactly* you're doing your removal.

Comment: @SuperOli - The removal happens during a save operation. Data access is 2 tier so "deleting" an item from the Grid really means marking it for deletion. Edits are batched, including deleted items, and sent to the server during a save event. When I get the list of items back from the server I have to check client side to see what operations succeeded, failed, etc... A successful delete operation means I can remove the item from the underlying collection. However, I have created a simple solution to test this independently with the same results.

Comment: Stupid question... do you fix the validation error before the removal? Because in the application I created to reproduce your bug here, my cell stays in "edit mode" until I cancel my change (ESC) or put a valid string. Another thing you might want to try, is download the DataGrid source code from Codeplex (http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and reference this instead. Maybe that way, you'll be able to debug the DataGrid state.

Comment: No, the validation error is not fixed before removal, which is the originating problem of the question. When removing the underlying object that a row is bound to, if that row has a validation error, then the DataGrid stays in an invalid state even though the row has been removed visually.

Comment: Debugged a little bit and found out that the private property DataGrid.HasCellValidationError remains "true" after your row removal. It's only set when an edition is committed (in DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit() to be more precise). When this property is true, it prevents entering "Edit Mode". In my opinion it looks like a bug and should be reported to Microsoft. I guess you'd like to find a workaround?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. @Josh: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Meleak: I don't remember the exact solution I came up with, but it was a big gnarly hack, and it didn't eliminate the problem completely. There were instances where it was possible to get into the bad state. I was going to open a bug report with MS, but forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a long search process I found a solution:

You can create a class which is derived from the DataGrid. There you can access the private properties by reflection. If you now remove an invalid item you can call the function SetGridWritable() and the other values are editable again.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public void SetGridWritable()
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        PropertyInfo cellErrorInfo = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasCellValidationError", bindingFlags);
        PropertyInfo rowErrorInfo = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasRowValidationError", bindingFlags);
        cellErrorInfo.SetValue(this, false, null);
        rowErrorInfo.SetValue(this, false, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a few hours trying to find out what's going on. Finally, a simple refresh on Items solved the issue. Hope this helps.

```
YourDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: Where would you put this refresh?!

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-solution solution if you're interested:

We've found the whole validation mechanism to be full of unwanted behavior.
For example - we want to allow our users to enter invalid data, and only mark the error.

To do this we created a cell template with a red frame which is bound with a data trigger that is invoked whenever the error state of a given property changes.
The actual creation of the datatrigger is done by a dependency property that receives the binding path to the property of the ViewModel and creates the binding

i.e:

```
DataTrigger errorTrigger = CreateTrigger(CreateDirectBinding(property,new HasErrorValueConverter()), CreateErrorSetter(property));
```

This works around the problems associated with validation errors.