# WPF DataGrid IDataErrorInfo can't set data through DataBinding (Bug?)

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

Related Question: [WPF DataGrid Validation Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034065/wpf-datagrid-validation-bug)

You have the following DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding .}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Header="Name" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeNameCommand}">...</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

1. Enter some invalid data
2. Click on the button which will do something like Name="Something";
   (Yes OnPropertyChanged is fired). Result: The DataGrid shows the new value but still the red exclamation mark.
3. Select another item in the grid. 
   Result: The previous selected item contains again the invalid data!

This seems to be a bug. But what can I do to change the underlying ViewModel (f.e. if I am using a OpenFileDialog)

ViewModel:

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_name == "Error")
                return "Name is Error";

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeNameCommand { get; protected set; }

    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        ChangeNameCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { Name = "Another Name"; });
    }
}
```

DataContext is set to an ObservableCollection of ItemViewModel

Comment: you need to add information of your itemssource. what kind of object is it? DataTable or Object with just IDataErrorInfo implemented or any other?

Comment: any why you need a button to set the value of your Name property?

Comment: Ok I edit my question and post the code of my ItemViewModel. I need a button f.e. to open a OpenFileDialog and set a Path to a File or something else.